# Issue dual booting Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Windows 7 PC that I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on and have been able to run and have used in the past.  Now, when I go to boot Ubuntu, it locks up and dumps the stack and what I took away from it was a thread issue with a semaphore.  I would like to uninstall Ubuntu without compromising my Windows system, but I have no desire to save anything on the Ubuntu system.  How can I do this from within Windows?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @user3114046 please do not send crap. It was rejected in AU.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delete all the partitions that Linux is installed over (home, root, and swap) then reboot with the W7 CD/DVD in, and enter the repair computer section of the W7 installer.

Once in the installer select 'repair my computer' and then use the Command Prompt

Type:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

And for good measure

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

Reboot.